# Arel table relational division

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, arel, relational-division

I'm using Rails 5.1 with PostgreSQL 9.5 and am new to Arel tables. I'm trying to create a query (which I hope to eventually chain with other scopes queries) which returns records where all of the associated records match the given input.

Given an array of `weekday_ids: [1, 2, 5, 6]`, return only `ranges` which have active `time_slots` matching **all** the given `weekday_ids`

**Models**

```
class Range < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :time_slots
end

class TimeSlot < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :range
  belongs_to :weekday
end
```

**Working example which returns expected results**

```
def self.qualified_time_slots(weekday_ids = nil)
  weekday_ids ||= [1, 2, 5, 6]

  qualified_ranges = Range.includes(:time_slots).all.map do |range|
    active_time_slots = range.time_slots.where(active: true)
    range if weekday_ids.all? { |day| active_time_slots.map(&:weekday_id).include? day }
  end

  # return
  qualified_ranges.compact
end
```

**Current non-working attempt at Arel Query to achieve the same as above method**

```
Range.joins(
  :time_slots
).where(
  time_slots: { active: true }
).where(
  TimeSlot.arel_table[:weekday_id].in(weekday_ids)
)
```

**Expected Results**

```
# Should return:
[
  range: {
    id: 1, 
    time_slots: [
      { weekday_id: 1 },
      { weekday_id: 2 },
      { weekday_id: 5 },
      { weekday_id: 6 },
    ]
  },
  range: {
    id: 2, 
    time_slots: [
      { weekday_id: 0 },
      { weekday_id: 1 },
      { weekday_id: 2 },
      { weekday_id: 3 },
      { weekday_id: 4 },
      { weekday_id: 5 },
      { weekday_id: 6 },
    ]
  }
]


# Should NOT return 
[
  range: {
    id: 3, 
    time_slots: [
      { weekday_id: 1 },
      { weekday_id: 2 },
      { weekday_id: 5 },
    ]
  },

  range: {
    id: 4, 
    time_slots: [
      { weekday_id: 0 },
      { weekday_id: 6 },
    ]
  }
]
```

**EDIT** - In working though this, I've followed the examples from a [Joe Celko article on Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) and created this raw SQL query which, appears to work, but has not yet bet thoroughly tested:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("
  SELECT 
    ts.range_id
  FROM 
    time_slots AS ts
  WHERE 
    ts.active = true
  AND 
    ts.weekday_id IN (#{weekday_ids.join(',')})
  GROUP BY 
    ts.range_id 
  HAVING COUNT(weekday_id) >= #{weekday_ids.length};
")
```

Comment: Does it work to chain the `.in`s?

Comment: I suspect chaining them will cause it to be ands, not sure, just a wild guess, not enough time to test and answer properly

Comment: at any rate, you need ands, not ors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still testing this, but it looks like this is working:

```
Range.joins(
  :time_slots
).where(
  TimeSlot.arel_table[:active].eq(
    true
  ).and(
    TimeSlot.arel_table[:weekday_id].in(
      weekday_ids
    )
  )
).group(
  Range.arel_table[:id]
).having(
  TimeSlot.arel_table[:weekday_id].count(true).gteq(weekday_ids.count)
)
```